# Bootstrap with select list that contains only images

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap for my frontend. I need a select input component that has only images as options. I can only find such a component with JQuery UI, which is not part of Bootstrap. Is there any component like this for Boostrap?

Comment: Albeit a bit bloated, why not just use jQuery-UI if it has what you need? You can get a custom download so you include only specific parts... And Im hesitant, but this is border line off-topic

Comment: @Oberst because it will have a different look than the Bootstrap components. It will look ugly!

Answer (score 4):

The [Bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) component has a `data-content` attribute that you can use. See this example:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/css/base.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js">
<script src="https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/js/base.js"></script>
<select class="selectpicker">
    <option data-content='<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/54/Gota07.svg/120px-Gota07.svg.png">'>Teardrop</option>
    <option data-content='<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1a/Emblem-club.svg/120px-Emblem-club.svg.png">'>Club</option>
    <option data-content='<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Emblem-spade.svg/120px-Emblem-spade.svg.png">'>Spade</option>
    <option data-content='<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bf/Luneta07.svg/120px-Luneta07.svg.png">'>Moon</option>
    <option data-content='<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/Emblem-important-black.svg/120px-Emblem-important-black.svg.png">'>Exclamation</option>
</select>
<p style="padding-bottom: 100px"></p>
```

Comment: When I run the code snippet ... I don't see any images!?